# Удалить кусок html используя xpath

Tags: html, python, xpath

Задача может быть и простая, но я с таким не сталкивался. Как из html-кода удалить определенный узел? Используя xpath шаблон. Ниже примерно описал алгоритм. Не знаю только библиотеку и функцию, которые выполнили бы эту операцию.

```
import "какая_нибудь_стандартная_библиотека"
html_code = '<html><head><title>Заголовок</title></head> и так далее ...</html>'
xpath_parrent = '//title'
result = "функция_удалить"(html_code, xpath_parrent)
теперь узла title больше нету
можно выводить на экран
print title
```

Comment: Подозреваю, что нужно выбрать все узлы, название которых не title.

Comment: xpath запрос не получится. Трансформация xsl + xpath с рекурсией, плюс с условием прийдётся помучатся.

Answer (score 3):

Используя модуль `lxml` можно удалить через метод [remove](https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html):

```py
from lxml import html

html_code = '<html><head><title>Заголовок</title></head><body></body></html>'
root = html.fromstring(html_code)

for el in root.xpath('//title'):
    parent = el.getparent()
    parent.remove(el)

print(html.tostring(root))
# b'<html><head></head><body></body></html>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Чистый xpath запрос не получится, потому что функция selectNodes выбирает Nod-ы из одного уровня xml, и фильтр можно поставить только на весь уровень. Но можно сделать, например, `SelectNodes('/*/*[name(*/.)!="title"]')` что выберет "второй" уровень (т.к. первый "root" т.е. весь документ тег html), при этом будет отброшена вся ветка `head`, от этого вы никак не уйдёте, т.к. если выбрать третий уровень - елементы второго уровня где нету третьего "уйдут" потеряются данные. Пример тут http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36260599/xpath-search-within-xpath-results

---

Вариант 2. Можно использовать трансформацию xsl + xpath с рекурсией. Скрипт трансформации будет примерно такой:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet  version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
   xmlns:reportdefinition="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition"  
   xmlns:rd = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner"
   exclude-result-prefixes="xmlns">

<xsl:template match="*" mode="copyif">
<xsl:if test="name(.)!='title'">
<xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;', name(.) )"  disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
<xsl:for-each  select="@*">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(' ',name(.),'=&#34;',.,'&#34;')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
</xsl:for-each>
<xsl:value-of select="'>'" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
<xsl:value-of select="text()" />
<xsl:apply-templates mode="copyif" select="*" />
<xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;/', name(.) ,'>&#13;')"  disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" >
<xsl:apply-templates mode="copyif" select="*" />
</xsl:template>
```

Базируется на функции `copyif` которая клонирует ноды, плюс в `if` - условие копирование (c которыи прийдётся помучатся, сравнение полного пути xpath 3.0 поддерживает). Шапку можно и 1.0, функции "базовые". Запрос большой, зато на питоне будет две-три строчки - загрузить два xml и сделать transform. это  не самый лучший метод, но может пригодится как пример обращения с xml.